# Qml textbox not moving up

Tags: qt, input, textbox, symbian, qml

My text input in qml used to flick up to above the keyboard so that you can see what you're typing. (I did not add it this was standard). Now it doesn't go up any more. I think this was after I updated the SDK. Any idea what could be causing this and what I can do to fix it?

I have also tried the native Symbian text input in qml but it give the same results.

This happens on the real device

The text input works typing puts characters into the text box but the text box doesn't move up to above the keyboard like normal it stays low and you can't see what you're typing until you close the keyboard.

Comment: this happens in simulator or real device ?

Comment: This happens on the real device

Answer (score 0):

Typically the device should open the keyboard panel by itself, if indeed you've selected (activated) the keyboard input field (are you sure you have?  Does the cursor appear when you click on it?)

You could always call `item.openSoftwareInputPanel()` in an `onClicked:` clause if you want to force it.